# CSS issue when changing vanilla javascript over to React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm in the process of rebuilding the frontend of an app that was originally written using vanilla javascript and changing it over to a React framework.  For some reason though, I'm having trouble with some of the styling of the HTML elements.  Specifically, the textarea at the bottom is the incorrect size, the buttons at the bottom are also the incorrect size and not aligned as they should.  I've changed all of the "class" attributes to "className" since I'm using JSX.  I've searched for other typos or some other attribute that might be different with JSX but I find myself stuck.

This page is also opened up as a 400 x 500 electron window.  It works perfectly fine when I load the original HTML file.

**Update 5/3/2021 @ 3:43PM EST**
So I've noticed that in my JSX file, the textarea won't accept what I enter as values for the rows and cols attributes.  Further, the submit button (id="submit_button") won't accept any of the css from the buttons class but the cancel button will.

**Original HTML File**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Feedback</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/feedback.css"/>
            <script defer src="../src/feedback.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="window_frame" id="frame">
                <title id="window_title"> </title>
                <button id="close" tabindex="-1"><svg width="40" height="30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><line stroke="#afafaf" stroke-width="1.25" id="svg_1" y2="6.4" x2="28.6" y1="23.6" x1="11.4" /><line stroke="#afafaf" stroke-width="1.25" id="svg_2" y2="23.6" x2="28.6" y1="6.4" x1="11.4"/></g></svg></button>
            </div>
            
            <form name="upload_feedback" id="feedback_form" onsubmit="return false">
                <p>How would you rate your experience?</p>
                <div class="star_rating" id="star_rating">
                    <input value="0" id="star0_exp" checked type="radio" name="rating_exp" class="visuallyhidden">
                        <label for="star0_exp">
                            <span class="visuallyhidden">0 Stars</span>
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                         
                            </svg>
                        </label>
    
                    <input value="1" id="star1_exp" type="radio" name="rating_exp" class="visuallyhidden">
                        <label for="star1_exp">
                            <span class="visuallyhidden">1 Star</span>
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </label>
    
                    <input value="2" id="star2_exp" type="radio" name="rating_exp" class="visuallyhidden">
                        <label for="star2_exp">
                            <span class="visuallyhidden">2 Stars</span>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                    <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                </svg>
                        </label>
    
                    <input value="3" id="star3_exp" type="radio" name="rating_exp" class="visuallyhidden">
                        <label for="star3_exp">
                            <span class="visuallyhidden">3 Stars</span>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                    <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                </svg>
                        </label>
    
                    <input value="4" id="star4_exp" type="radio" name="rating_exp" class="visuallyhidden">
                        <label for="star4_exp">
                            <span class="visuallyhidden">4 Stars</span>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                    <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                </svg>
                        </label>
    
                    <input value="5" id="star5_exp" type="radio" name="rating_exp" class="visuallyhidden">
                        <label for="star5_exp">
                            <span class="visuallyhidden">5 Stars</span>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                    <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                </svg>
                        </label>
                    <output></output>
                </div>
                <p>How likely are you to recommend this app to other users?</p>
                <div class="star_rating" id="star_rating">
                    <input value="0" id="star0" checked type="radio" name="rating" class="visuallyhidden">
                        <label for="star0">
                            <span class="visuallyhidden">0 Stars</span>
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                        
                            </svg>
                        </label>
    
                    <input value="1" id="star1" type="radio" name="rating" class="visuallyhidden">
                        <label for="star1">
                            <span class="visuallyhidden">1 Star</span>
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </label>
    
                    <input value="2" id="star2" type="radio" name="rating" class="visuallyhidden">
                        <label for="star2">
                            <span class="visuallyhidden">2 Stars</span>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                    <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                </svg>
                        </label>
    
                    <input value="3" id="star3" type="radio" name="rating" class="visuallyhidden">
                        <label for="star3">
                            <span class="visuallyhidden">3 Stars</span>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                    <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                </svg>
                        </label>
    
                    <input value="4" id="star4" type="radio" name="rating" class="visuallyhidden">
                        <label for="star4">
                            <span class="visuallyhidden">4 Stars</span>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                    <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                </svg>
                        </label>
    
                    <input value="5" id="star5" type="radio" name="rating" class="visuallyhidden">
                        <label for="star5">
                            <span class="visuallyhidden">5 Stars</span>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                    <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                </svg>
                        </label>
                    <output></output>
                </div>
                <p>Please provide more information:</p>
                <textarea name="feedback" form="feedback_form" spellcheck="false" id="feedback" name="feedback" label="Feedback" rows="8" cols="50" placeholder="Feedback" autofocus></textarea>
                <div class="buttons">
                        <button type="button" id="cancel_feedback">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" id="submit_button">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Original JS File**

```
    const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer
    
    //event handler to display window frame if platform isn't macos
    ipc.on('display-frame', (event, title) => {
        document.getElementById('frame').style.display = 'block'
        document.getElementById('window_title').innerHTML = title
    })
    
    //event handler for creation attempt
    document.getElementById('submit_button').addEventListener('click', () => {
        //reset background color of the feedback form
        document.getElementById('feedback').style.backgroundColor = "#4f4f4f"
    
        //get feedback text
        var feedbackText = document.getElementById('feedback').value
        var feedbackStarsExp = 0;
        var feedbackStarsRec = 0;
         //get rating from stars
        if (document.querySelector('input[name="rating_exp"]:checked') ) {
            feedbackStarsExp = document.querySelector('input[name="rating_exp"]:checked').value;
        }
           
        if (document.querySelector('input[name="rating"]:checked') ) {
            feedbackStarsRec = document.querySelector('input[name="rating"]:checked').value;
        }
       
        //send feedback info to main process
        ipc.send('upload-feedback', {feedbackText: feedbackText, experienceRating: feedbackStarsExp, 
            recommendRating: feedbackStarsRec})
    })
    
    //event handlers for page close
    document.getElementById('cancel_feedback').addEventListener('click', () => ipc.send('close-feedback-page'))
    document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', () => ipc.send('close-feedback-page'))
```

**JSX File**

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    import WindowFrame from "../window_frame/WindowFrame.jsx";
    import "./feedback.css";
    
    const ipc = window.require("electron").ipcRenderer
    
    const Feedback = () => {
    
        const operatingSystem = useSelector((state) => state.operatingSystem)
    
        const [experienceRating, setExperienceRating] = useState(0);
        const [recommendRating, setRecommendRating] = useState(0);
        const [feedbackText, setFeedbackText] = useState("");
    
        console.log("EXP: ", experienceRating)
        console.log("REC: ", recommendRating)
        console.log("TEXT: ", feedbackText)
    
        const handleFeedbackSubmit = (e) =>{
            e.preventDefault()
            ipc.send('upload-feedback', {
                feedbackText: feedbackText,
                experienceRating: experienceRating,
                recommendRating: recommendRating
            })
        }
    
        return (
            <div>
                {operatingSystem.indexOf('Mac') >= 0 ? null : <WindowFrame window="feedback"/>}
                <form name="upload_feedback" id="feedback_form" onSubmit={(e) => handleFeedbackSubmit(e)}>
                    <p>How would you rate your experience?</p>
                    <div className="star_rating" id="star_rating" onChange={(e) => setExperienceRating(e.target.value)}>
                        <input value="0" id="star0_exp" checked type="radio" name="rating_exp" className="visuallyhidden"></input>
                            <label htmlFor="star0_exp">
                                <span className="visuallyhidden">0 Stars</span>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512"></svg>
                            </label>
                        <input value="1" id="star1_exp" type="radio" name="rating_exp" className="visuallyhidden"></input>
                            <label htmlFor="star1_exp">
                                <span className="visuallyhidden">1 Star</span>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                    <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </label>
                        <input value="2" id="star2_exp" type="radio" name="rating_exp" className="visuallyhidden"></input>
                            <label htmlFor="star2_exp">
                                <span className="visuallyhidden">2 Stars</span>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                        <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                            </label>
                        <input value="3" id="star3_exp" type="radio" name="rating_exp" className="visuallyhidden"></input>
                            <label htmlFor="star3_exp">
                                <span className="visuallyhidden">3 Stars</span>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                        <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                            </label>
                        <input value="4" id="star4_exp" type="radio" name="rating_exp" className="visuallyhidden"></input>
                            <label htmlFor="star4_exp">
                                <span className="visuallyhidden">4 Stars</span>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                        <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                            </label>
                        <input value="5" id="star5_exp" type="radio" name="rating_exp" className="visuallyhidden"></input>
                            <label htmlFor="star5_exp">
                                <span className="visuallyhidden">5 Stars</span>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                        <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                            </label>
                        <output></output>
                    </div>
                    <p>How likely are you to recommend this app to other users?</p>
                    <div className="star_rating" id="star_rating" onChange={(e) => setRecommendRating(e.target.value)}>
                        <input value="0" id="star0" type="radio" name="rating" className="visuallyhidden"></input>
                            <label htmlFor="star0">
                                <span className="visuallyhidden">0 Stars</span>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512"></svg>
                            </label>
                        <input value="1" id="star1" type="radio" name="rating" className="visuallyhidden"></input>
                            <label htmlFor="star1">
                                <span className="visuallyhidden">1 Star</span>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                    <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </label>
                        <input value="2" id="star2" type="radio" name="rating" className="visuallyhidden" ></input>
                            <label htmlFor="star2">
                                <span className="visuallyhidden">2 Stars</span>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                        <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                            </label>
                        <input value="3" id="star3" type="radio" name="rating" className="visuallyhidden"></input>
                            <label htmlFor="star3">
                                <span className="visuallyhidden">3 Stars</span>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                        <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                            </label>
                        <input value="4" id="star4" type="radio" name="rating" className="visuallyhidden" ></input>
                            <label htmlFor="star4">
                                <span className="visuallyhidden">4 Stars</span>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                        <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                            </label>
                        <input value="5" id="star5" type="radio" name="rating" className="visuallyhidden"></input>
                            <label htmlFor="star5">
                                <span className="visuallyhidden">5 Stars</span>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                        <path d="M512 198.525l-176.89-25.704-79.11-160.291-79.108 160.291-176.892 25.704 128 124.769-30.216 176.176 158.216-83.179 158.216 83.179-30.217-176.176 128.001-124.769z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                            </label>
                        <output></output>
                    </div>
                    <p>Please provide more information</p>
                    <textarea name="feedback" form="feedback_form" spellcheck="false" id="feedback" label="Feedback" cols={50} rows={8} placeholder="Feedback" autofocus onChange={(e) => setFeedbackText(e.target.value)} />
                    <div className="buttons">
                        <button type="button" id="cancel_feedback" onClick={() => ipc.send('close-feedback-page')}>Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" id="submit_button">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Feedback;
```

**CSS File**

```
    
    @import "../../styles/fonts.css";
    @import "../window_frame/window_frame.css";
    
    p {
        color: #efefef;
        font-size: 13px;
        margin: 20px 30px;
    }
    
    form {
        font-family: "Open Sans";
        color: #efefef;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 11px;
        
    }
    
    .star_rating{
        display:flex; 
        justify-content:space-evenly;  
    }
    
    #feedback {
        margin: 10px 30px;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        background-color: #4f4f4f;
        font-family: "Open Sans";
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #efefef;
        resize: none;
    }
    
    .buttons button {
        margin: 20px 30px;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 2px;
        width: 80px;
        height: 25px;
        background-color: #2f2f2f;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: "Open Sans";
        color: #efefef;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .buttons button:hover {
        background-color: #3f3f3f !important;
    }
    
    .buttons button:active {
        background-color: #4f4f4f !important;
    }
    
    #star_rating svg {
        width: 0.5em;
        height: 0.5em;
        fill: currentColor;
        stroke: currentColor;
    }
    
    #star_rating label, #star_rating output {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        font-size: 2em;
        height: 1.2em;
        color: rgb(238, 219, 111);
        cursor: pointer;
        /* Transparent border-bottom avoids jumping
           when a colored border is applied
             on :hover/:focus */
        border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    }
    #star_rating output {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        padding: 0 1em;
    }
    #star_rating input:checked ~ label {
        color: #999;
    }
    #star_rating input:checked + label {
        color: rgb(238, 219, 111);;
    }
    
    #star_rating:hover input + label {
        color: rgb(238, 219, 111);;
    }
    #star_rating input:hover ~ label,
    #star_rating input:focus ~ label,
    #star_rating input[id="star0"] + label {
        color: #999;
    }
    #star_rating input:hover + label,
    #star_rating input:focus + label {
        color:rgb(238, 219, 111);;
    }
    
    .visuallyhidden { 
        position: absolute; 
        overflow: hidden; 
        clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
        height: 1px; width: 1px; 
        margin: -1px; padding: 0; border: 0; 
      }
    
    .buttons{
      display:flex; 
      justify-content:space-evenly;  
    }
    
    #submit_button:focus,  #cancel_feedback:focus{
        background-color: #3f3f3f;
    }
    
    #submit_button:hover, #cancel_feedback:hover {
        background-color: #3f3f3f;
    }
    
    #submit_button:active, #cancel_feedback:active {
        background-color: #4f4f4f;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm relatively new to React and one thing I didn't realize is that other CSS files were impacting the current page I was working on.

I had another page called "issue_reporter" with its own CSS file where I had styling for ALL textareas.  This styling was affecting every other page where I was using a textarea even though I wasn't importing this CSS file to those pages.

I was able to solve this by changing the styling in the "issue_reporter" to only affect its id instead of ALL text files.  I did something similar for the buttons.

so in my issue_reporter.css file, this...

```
**textarea**{
    overflow: auto;
    width: 94%;
    height: 80px;
    resize: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    color: #efefef;
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 10px;   
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

became this...

```
**#issue_step** {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 94%;
    height: 80px;
    resize: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    color: #efefef;
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 10px;   
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```